Prove for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$,that if $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$ then $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{1+2bc} \geq \frac{3}{5}$
Given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, the question is to prove : $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{1+2bc} \geq \frac{3}{5}$$
I wasn't able to but managed to prove a weaker version using Titu's lemma, I proved that
$$\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a^2}{1+2bc}}  \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{5}$$
but of course $(a+b+c)^2 \leq 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = 3$.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

I have edited it, is that better?

Yes, it is better.

On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1300550p6925440, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1714511p11069147

Since $2bc \le b^2+c^2$ we have $${a^2\over 1+2bc}\geq {a^2\over 1+b^2+c^2}= {a^2\over 2-a^2}$$ Using tangent line method at $x= 1/3$ for $f(x)={x\over 2-x}$ we get $f(x) \geq {18x-1\over 25}\;\;\;$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.
No it is not hard to finish.


$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2}{1+2bc} \geq \dfrac 3 5, a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

\begin{align}
& \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2}{1+2bc} = \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2}{a^2+(b+c)^2}. \\
& \left( \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2}{a^2+(b+c)^2} \right) \left( \sum_{cyc} (a^2+(b+c)^2) \right) \geq (a+b+c)^2. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \left( \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {a^2}{a^2+(b+c)^2} \right) \geq \dfrac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca)}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca)}
\end{align}
Using $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca$, we can say that:
$\displaystyle \left( \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {a^2}{a^2+(b+c)^2} \right) \geq 1 - \dfrac {2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca)} \\ \geq 1 - \dfrac {2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(a^2+b^2+c^2)} = \dfrac 3 5. $
edit. I noticed that there wasn’t a positive condition.
Suggest that $ab < 0$, then $0 \leq (a+b)^2+c^2 = 1+2ab<1-2ab$, so  $\dfrac{c^2}{1+2ab} > \dfrac{c^2}{1-2ab}$, showing that $ab$ being negative leads to bigger value of it.

This was exactly my attempt, though I used Titu's lemma to do it directly, but how do you reduce the numerator in the final term? because, as I said, you cant reduce that further to get 3/5 since $(a+b+c)^2 \leq 3$ and $ab+bc+ca \leq 1$. But I might be wrong. Can you expand?

@Al-Mutaallim Just with my edit, you can assume $a, b, c$ to be positive reals. Then leave only $a^2+b^2+c^2$ in the numerator by transforming it to $1-\dfrac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca)}$ then use the inequality above to eliminate $ab+bc+ca$.

You can also use CS inequality like so (with $\sum$ denoting cyclic sums):
$$\sum \frac{a^4}{a^2+2a^2bc} \geqslant \frac{(\sum a^2)^2}{\sum a^2+2abc\sum a}=\frac1{1+2abc\sum a}$$
so it is enough to show $3abc\sum a\leqslant 1=(\sum a^2)^2=\sum a^4+2\sum a^2b^2$, which is obvious by Muirhead (or AM-GM).
